# Mexican Pesos and bitcoin

Tags: currencies

Are there any exchanges that convert bitcoin or other crypto currencies to non major fiat currencies like the Mexican peso?

Answer (score 1):

On https://bitcoin.org/en/exchanges, you can find exchanges of many countries. For Mexico, https://bitso.com and https://www.volabit.com are listed. Both allow for conversion between MXN and BTC.